# How to calculate table cells from a column

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make my table calculate cells from a column.

Example of the table:

[image: example]

So the amount is an input field in 5th column and total is already calculated from amount * price. And I would like to calculate all the amounts together and add it to the last row (dynamically created, id lastRow). And same to the totals.

So basically the question is how can I access all the cells from 5th column and add them together? And then the same thing to 6th column. It also needs to work if I add more rows. I have tried it like this but I don't know how to continue:

```
function calculate () {
    var col = 4;
    var rows = tabell.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var sum = 0;

    for (var i = 1; 1 < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = rows[i];
        var column = row.children('td')[col];
        sum += parseInt(column);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

No jQuery tips, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `row.children('td')[col]` is a `<td></td>` element, not the cell data; you should be looking at `row.children('td')[col].textContent`. You could simplify a bit by using `Array.from` to convert the rows to an array and `Array.reduce` that by adding `parseInt(row.cells[col].textContent, 10)` to the sum:

```
function calculate () {
    var col = 4;
    var rows = Array.from(tabell.rows);

    return rows.reduce((acc, row) => {
        return acc + parseInt(row.cells[col].textContent, 10);
    }, 0);
}
```

Here is the non-es6 version:

```
function calculate () {
    var col = 4;
    var rows = [].slice.call(tabell.rows, 0);

    return rows.reduce(function(acc, row) {
        return acc + parseInt(row.cells[col].textContent, 10);
    }, 0);
}
```

You can [learn more about `Array.reduce` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Here is a `for` loop version of what is happening:

```
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
   sum += parseInt(rows[i].cells[col].textContent, 10);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't quite get it. I'm just a beginner with javascript and I don't really understand what array.reduce etc means. Or how I should continue from that, do I still need a for loop or what?

Comment: You wouldn't need a for loop anymore, this replaces that. Array reduce collapses an array, in this case down to a single number.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple way of doing this is by using classes in your HTML. You can add one class to your 5th column cells, and another to your 6th column cells. After that you simply loop through that classes' elements and sum them up.

HTML sample

```
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td class="col5">3</td>
  <td class="col6">6</td>
</tr>
```

Javascript

```
function calc() {
  //Gather columns in arrays
  var col5 = document.getElementsByClassName('col5');
  var col6 = document.getElementsByClassName('col6');

  //Start sums at 0
  var sum5 = 0, sum6 = 0;

  //Loop through each column and add up sums
  for(var i = 0; i < col5.length; i++) {
    sum5 += parseInt(col5[i].innerHTML);
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < col6.length; i++) {
    sum6 += parseInt(col6[i].innerHTML);
  }

  //Store sums in total fields
  document.getElementById('total5').innerHTML = sum5;
  document.getElementById('total6').innerHTML = sum6;
}
```

[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/o4efq1sf/1/)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be a nice way to do it. In this case I'm sadly not allowed to change the html file (which doesn't have any classes or id's marked). This is part of a larger assignment for my class.

Comment: Nice answer! Note: you should include the `radix` param to `parseInt`, also `textContent` is probably a better option than `innerHTML` since tags could at some point have HTML in them which would mess up `parseInt`.